# Best way to convert multiple byte arrays to a single Java object?

Tags: java, arrays, json

**EDIT**:

I am not sure how much the WHY matters here. There are lot of reasons I am doing what I am doing in a certain way not feasible to explain in one post.
But I will still give some context, the service that stores my json files gives them back as byte arrays, so i start with byte[] arrays, each byte array is a json structure.

From this json i need to convert to a matching JAVA POJO this is POJO serves as a validator and then the final step is using Freemarker generating HTML files out of this POJO.

My scenario is that i get potentially get multiple byte arrays. Each can be a maximum of 500mb. I need to combine them, convert to JSON string and then convert to JAVA POJO.

There are couple of problems i am trying to address:

1. I see the jsonData only having 1000 records in all.
2. How do I combine the two jsons into one single json to be then able to convert to JAVA POJO?

Here's my JSON structure:

```
{
  "Header": {
    "id": 123
  },
  "Data": [
    {
      "key": "123
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my current code stripped to bare which I use for BYTE[] -> JSON STRING - > POJO

```java
byte[] dataFile = null;
for (String fileName : getFileNames()) {
        try {
          byte[] currentFile = null;
          currentFile = SomeService.getByteFile(fileName);
          dataFile = ArrayUtils.addAll(dataFile, currentFile);
        } 
String jsonData = new JSONObject(new String(dataFile)).toString();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
className classForMapping = mapper.readValue(jsonData, className.class));
```

Comment: "Byte arrays" are just completely unstructured data. What does "combine" mean? What sort of relationship does this blob have with JSON or POJOs? And why are you trying to put all of this into a single object?

Comment: (Note that if your code is remotely representative, then you have an insane JSON setup, but the sensible approach is to write a custom `Reader` or `InputStream` that wraps the underlying input _and discards it when finished with a segment_.)

Comment: Please see my edit if it helps?

Comment: Your "scenario" description seems inaccurate. _Each byte array_ is a JSON string (fair enough except for the crazy size), not parts of a JSON string that need to be concatenated before parsing. It sounds like you need to be producing a `List<Foo>` by processing your byte arrays. Note that Jackson has `readValue` options that take a `byte[]` directly.

Comment: I would convert byte arrays to (json) Strings, then deserialise each to a java object, then collect them to an array. I’m pretty sure this can be all done in 1 line.

Comment: @Bohemian can you please provide a sample/reference.